$\operatorname{ker}(q_I \otimes^{\text{min}} q_J) $ is a primal ideal of $\mathcal{A} \otimes^{\text{min}} \mathcal{B}$
In the proof of Theorem $4.1$ of the paper titled continuous bundles of $C^{\ast}$-algebras and tensor products following result is mention with a reference to Proposition $3.3$ of the paper "A. M. Zaki, Primal Ideals and tensor products of $C^{\ast}$
-algebras, J. Math. Phys. Sci. $24(1990), 171-176$" but I'm unable to find this paper.

Let $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ be $C^{\ast}$-algebras and $I$, $J$ be minimal primal ideals of $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ respectively. Then $\operatorname{ker}(q_I \otimes^{\text{min}} q_J) $ is a primal ideal of $\mathcal{A} \otimes^{\text{min}} \mathcal{B}$.

Can someone please give the proof or help me in finding the referred paper?
Recall that a closed subspace $I$ of a $C^{\ast}$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ is called $\mathbf{primal}$ if whenever $J_1J_2... J_n=\{0\}$ for some closed ideals $J_i$, then $J_i \subseteq I$ for at least one value of $i$.
